# Parameters not Passed Correctly between Two classes

Tags: c#, parameters

I had a very huge class(+1000 lines) so I split it based on Functionality(it should have been like that from start). I'll show what I did below, with a compact example.

```
class myOriginal
{
    int avariable = new int();
    myOriginalDerivedClass _myOriginalDerivedClass;
    public myOriginal()
    {
        _myOriginalDerivedClass = new myOriginalDerivedClass();
    }
    void mySortofMainFunction()
    {
        // doing something here
        avariable++;
        _myOriginalDerivedClass.adifferentFunction(avariable);

        // use avariable
    }
}

class myOriginalDerivedClass
{
    public myOriginalDerivedClass()
    {}

    public void adifferentFunction(int value)
    {
        if (someCondition is true)
        {
            value = 0;
            //something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I face is that, even when `someCondition is true` in `adifferentFunction()`still the value of `avariable` does not change. I am not able to figure it out. Do I have to use 'ref' keyword, as I am pointing out to an existing memory location and changing that instead of new one? Please help me out. The reason I declare 'avariable' outside the function is that I do not want to rest the value of it every time the function is called.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code. The code you've posted at the moment wouldn't even compile.

Comment: of course the `avariable` does not change, its just a simple int argument. please adjust your code as above said. there are more issues, for example you are talking about a "Derived" class but it is actually not. also the is keyword has a different meaning.

Comment: It would also help if you'd be clearer about what this method is doing - rather than thinking about it changing state, think about it computing a value... while using `ref` would indeed work, it may well be better to just make the method return an `int`, and use that to set the new value of `avariable`.

Comment: Instead of making these breaking changes just use partial classes so that you can keep the same class name and you can separate files for the functionalities.

This way the calling functions won't need any changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use référence to pass int value like this ref avariable https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your comments. I could return `int` but this was the simplest example. I have functions which adapt multiple parameters. I am inclined to use `ref` or `partial class`

Comment: If your method needs to mutate significant amount of state of the class, then it should be in the same class. It sounds like you should think differently about how to split your code up. (Using a partial class solves the physical "large file" issue, but nothing else - if your class has too many responsibilities, it doesn't change that at all.)